# Drag and drop with shinyjqui to a grid-table

Tags: html, jquery, r, shiny, shinyjqui

I'm experimenting with the shinyjqui package:

One particularly interesting function is `orderInput()`. With the `connect` argument, we can drag and drop items, as demonstrated here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyjqui/vignettes/orderInput.html

I'm attempting to drag and drop items into a grid table, but unfortunately, it's not functioning as expected.

Here's the code I've developed thus far:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)



connections <- c('my_grid') # id of the grid table


ui <- fluidPage(
 
  # some styling
   tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .grid-table {
        width: 150px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      .grid-cell {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        background-color: white;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .grid-cell-text {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: steelblue;
        color: white;
        font-size: 18px;
      }
      .droppable-cell {
        background-color: lightgray;
      }
      .table-container {
        display: flex;
        position: absolute;
        left: 550px;
        top: 30px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
    "))
  ),
  
  div(class = "table-container",
      div(class = "grid-table", id = "my_grid",
          div(class = "grid-row",
              div(class = "grid-cell grid-cell-text", "my_grid"),
              div(id = "droppable_cell_1", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
              div(id = "droppable_cell_2", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
              div(id = "droppable_cell_3", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
              div(id = "droppable_cell_4", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
              div(id = "droppable_cell_5", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
              div(id = "droppable_cell_6", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
              div(id = "droppable_cell_7", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", "")
          )
      ),
      
      orderInput('letters', 'Letters', items = LETTERS[1:7],
                 connect = connections) # defined above
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one example which has two changes: First, the `connections` parameter of the `orderInput` should not refer to the grid table, but rather to the grid cells:

```
connections <- paste0("droppable_cell_", 1:7)
```

Second, each of the grid cells has to be a `sortable` which is connected to `letters` and has an `append()` when dropping the letters on it. Since I currently do not get this to run with `shinyjqui` build-in functions, I implement it with a small custom `JS`:

```
$(function() {
    $('[id^=droppable_cell]').sortable({
        connectWith: '#letters',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
                  $(this).append(ui.draggable);
              }
    })
});
```

[image]

I also set `padding` to `5px` in the style of the `.grid-cell` such that the letters appear in the middle of the cells.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

connections <- paste0("droppable_cell_", 1:7) # id of the grid cells

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(
        JS(
            "
                       $(function() {
                           $('[id^=droppable_cell]').sortable({
                               connectWith: '#letters',
                               drop: function(event, ui) {
                                         $(this).append(ui.draggable);
                                     }
                           })
                        });
                        "
        )
    ),
    # some styling
    tags$style(
        HTML(
            "
            .grid-table {
                width: 150px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .grid-cell {
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                background-color: white;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .grid-cell-text {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: steelblue;
                color: white;
                font-size: 18px;
            }
            .droppable-cell {
                background-color: lightgray;
            }
            .table-container {
                display: flex;
                position: absolute;
                left: 550px;
                top: 30px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            "
        )
    )),
    
    div(
        class = "table-container",
        div(
            class = "grid-table",
            id = "my_grid",
            div(
                class = "grid-row",
                div(class = "grid-cell grid-cell-text", "my_grid"),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_1", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_2", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_3", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_4", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_5", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_6", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_7", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", "")
            )
        ),
        
        orderInput('letters', 'Letters', items = LETTERS[1:7],
                   connect = connections) # defined above
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: how would we setup if we add a second grid `my_grid2` and add the feature to also drag and drop between the grids e.g. `my_grid` and `my_grid2`?

Comment: Say we have a second grid table `my_grid2` in the table container, and its cell ids are `droppable_cell2_1` and so on. Then in the above example, change the selector `$('[id^=droppable_cell]')` to `$('[id^=droppable_cell_]')` and change `connectWith` to `'#letters, [id^=droppable_cell2]'`. This will establish the connection from grid 1 to grid 2. Also add the backwards direction similarly by using a function with selector `$('[id^=droppable_cell2]')` and `connectWith: $('[id^=droppable_cell_]')`. If you also want to DnD from grid2 and `letters`, then extend `connections` with the new cells.

Comment: Thank you again very much. IWill try out it out as soon as i am on my PC.

Comment: I tried it out, it works perfect!