# Implement drag-and-drop functionality using an observeEvent triggered by an actionButton in shinyjqui

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs, shinyjqui

This is a follow-up question to this [Drag and drop with shinyjqui to a grid-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76932753/drag-and-drop-with-shinyjqui-to-a-grid-table/76937125?noredirect=1#comment135632457_76937125)

This is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

connections <- paste0("droppable_cell_", 1:7) # id of the grid cells

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(tags$script(
        JS(
            "
                       $(function() {
                           $('[id^=droppable_cell]').sortable({
                               connectWith: '#letters',
                               drop: function(event, ui) {
                                         $(this).append(ui.draggable);
                                     }
                           })
                        });
                        "
        )
    ),
    # some styling
    tags$style(
        HTML(
            "
            .grid-table {
                width: 150px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .grid-cell {
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                background-color: white;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .grid-cell-text {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: steelblue;
                color: white;
                font-size: 18px;
            }
            .droppable-cell {
                background-color: lightgray;
            }
            .table-container {
                display: flex;
                position: absolute;
                left: 550px;
                top: 30px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            "
        )
    )),
    
    div(
        class = "table-container",
        div(
            class = "grid-table",
            id = "my_grid",
            div(
                class = "grid-row",
                div(class = "grid-cell grid-cell-text", "my_grid"),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_1", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_2", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_3", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_4", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_5", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_6", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_7", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", "")
            )
        ),
        
        orderInput('letters', 'Letters', items = LETTERS[1:7],
                   connect = connections) # defined above
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am attempting to implement drag-and-drop functionality using an observeEvent triggered by an actionButton. My objective is to enable dragging and dropping of a vector, let's say vec <- c(A, B, C), onto the my_grid table through a button click.

Context: The underlying concept involves preselecting and positioning items in specific locations within the my_grid. It's important to note that when items are moved to the my_grid, they should also vanish from the letters section.

Comment: So is your goal that in the current app everything stays at it is, except that at the start of the app the DnD functionality is disabled and that there is a button which enables the functionality? Or are there more requirements?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Both functionalities should remain, 1. DnD and 2. Control with buttons. I want to give the user some starting options with different combinations or more exactly with fixed combinations. So for button1  combination: my_grid first cell "A", for my_grid2 3 cell "E" .... etc. then a second button with different combinations, all stored in a vector e.g. vecComb1 and vecComb2. This and if possible to apply the bookmark feature to the app <https://shiny.posit.co/r/articles/share/bookmarking-state/> Many thanks!

Comment: In this example there is only my_grid. In my original there are more like my_grid2 and my_grid3 if we can make it work for one, I can transform it to the other!

Comment: Okay, thank you. I would like to try it, but unfortunately I still don't get it in detail. In your given example there is `my_grid` and there are letters from `A` to `G`. What shall the answer contain. We would add a button. If the user clicks the button, what shall happen then (with `my_grid`, with the letters or with other objects, how are the combinations defined)?

Comment: As you can see in `my_grid` there are 7 rows that we can fill by drag and drop (as done in your former answer). Now at the start of the app everything is the same but there is one button more called say: `btn_suggestion1`. By clicking this button the seven rows of my grid should be filled with `letters` like this: Row1 = A, Row2 = empty, Row3 = G, Row4= empty, Row5 = B, Row6 = C, Row7 = D. This information is stored in vector `vec_suggestion1 <- c(A, NA, G, NA, B, C, D)`. Now we create a second button say `btn_suggestion2` which contains items from `vec_suggestion2 <- c(A, B, C, D, E, F, G)`.

Comment: We would also need a button the brings back all the items to their list to clean my_grid, a kind of `Reset` button.

Comment: Okay, thank you. Concerning `vec_suggestion` 1 and 2: They shall be defined in your script, i.e. below `connections`? And the user sees only something like "suggestion 1" as the label of the first button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, we define two suggestions for the placement of the letters at the beginning, e.g. here as given by you

```
connections <- paste0("droppable_cell_", 1:7) # id of the grid cells

vec_suggestion1 <- c("A", NA, "G", NA, "B", "C", "D")
vec_suggestion2 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")

df <- data.frame(
    connections = connections,
    vec_suggestion1 = vec_suggestion1,
    vec_suggestion2 = vec_suggestion2
)
```

, and we would like to implement three buttons. Two of them are used for filling the grid as given by the two suggestions and one of them shall have a functionality for resetting the Drag and Drop. Also, the original Drag and Drop functionality has to stay as it is. This should look like this:

[image]

We use a `shinyjs` approach here which adds some custom `JS` functions to the buttons. I explain the important changes in the following and include the full minimal working example at the end.

The buttons are defined as usual inside the `ui`, e.g.

```
actionButton("btn_suggestion1", "Suggestion 1")
```

Inside the server, we use

```
shinyjs::js$pageCol(df)
    
observeEvent(input$btn_suggestion1, {
    shinyjs::disable("btn_suggestion1")
    shinyjs::js$setSuggestion(1)
    shinyjs::enable("btn_suggestion1")
})
```

As requested by you, the `observeEvent` is triggered by the button and will basically call a function `setSuggestion` with parameter 1. The 1 is the column index of the choices in `df` (since `JS` indices start with 0). The function is defined inside `pageCol`, which is the important part here. `pageCol` gets `df` as a parameter and contains

1. The original definition of the sortable as given in the question.
2. Some variable declarations which are needed for the buttons.

```
  var dataArray = Object.values(params[0]);
  dataArray = dataArray[0].map((col, i) => dataArray.map(row => row[i]));
  
  var cacheLetters = $('#letters').html();
  var cacheGridCells = $('[id^=droppable_cell]').html();
```

`dataArray` is just `df` converted into `JS`, and we transpose it for convenience. `cacheLetters` and `cacheGridCells` are used for saving the original state of the letters and the grid (this will be used for the reset button later).

3. The `setSuggestion` function

```
  shinyjs.setSuggestion = function (idxSuggestion) {
    
    // loop over the array rows
    $.each(dataArray, function (index, value) {

        // define the selector for the grid cell using the first array column
        var cellSelector = '#' + dataArray[index][0];

        // define the new innerHTML of the grid cell such that it will
        // contain the shinyjqui sortable element
        var cellHTML = '<div data-value=\"' 
                        + dataArray[index][idxSuggestion] 
                        + '\" class=\"btn btn-default ui-sortable-handle\" style=\"margin: 1px;\" jqui_sortable_idx=\"letters__' 
                        + (index + 1).toString() 
                        + '\">' 
                        + dataArray[index][idxSuggestion] 
                        + '</div>';
        
        // if the current value is na, next
        if (dataArray[index][idxSuggestion] === null) {
            return true;
        }
        
        // change the innerHTML of the grid cell such that it gets the letter attached
        $(cellSelector).html(cellHTML);
        
        // drop the current letter from the original list
        $('#letters').find(`[data-value='${dataArray[index][idxSuggestion]}']`)[0].remove()
    })
  }
```

4. The `resetDnD` function.

```
  shinyjs.resetDnD = function (params){
    $('#letters').html(cacheLetters).sortable('refresh');
    $('[id^=droppable_cell]').html(cacheGridCells).sortable('refresh');
  }
```

It just refreshes the letters and the droppable cells using the initially cached `HTML` of the elements.

Here is the complete example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)
library(shinyjs)

connections <- paste0("droppable_cell_", 1:7) # id of the grid cells

vec_suggestion1 <- c("A", NA, "G", NA, "B", "C", "D")
vec_suggestion2 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")

df <- data.frame(
    connections = connections,
    vec_suggestion1 = vec_suggestion1,
    vec_suggestion2 = vec_suggestion2
)

js <- "shinyjs.pageCol = function(params){

  $('[id^=droppable_cell]').sortable({
     connectWith: '#letters',
     drop: function(event, ui) {
               $(this).append(ui.draggable);
            }
  })
  
  var dataArray = Object.values(params[0]);
  dataArray = dataArray[0].map((col, i) => dataArray.map(row => row[i]));
  
  var cacheLetters = $('#letters').html();
  var cacheGridCells = $('[id^=droppable_cell]').html();
  
  shinyjs.setSuggestion = function (idxSuggestion) {
    
    $.each(dataArray, function (index, value) {
        var cellSelector = '#' + dataArray[index][0];
        var cellHTML = '<div data-value=\"' 
                        + dataArray[index][idxSuggestion] 
                        + '\" class=\"btn btn-default ui-sortable-handle\" style=\"margin: 1px;\" jqui_sortable_idx=\"letters__' 
                        + (index + 1).toString() 
                        + '\">' 
                        + dataArray[index][idxSuggestion] 
                        + '</div>';
        
        if (dataArray[index][idxSuggestion] === null) {
            return true;
        }
        
        $(cellSelector).html(cellHTML);
        
        $('#letters').find(`[data-value='${dataArray[index][idxSuggestion]}']`)[0].remove()
    })
  }
  
  shinyjs.resetDnD = function (params){
    $('#letters').html(cacheLetters).sortable('refresh');
    $('[id^=droppable_cell]').html(cacheGridCells).sortable('refresh');
  }
};
"

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    extendShinyjs(text = js, functions = c("pageCol", "resetDnD", "setSuggestion")),
    tags$head(
    # some styling
    tags$style(
        HTML(
            "
            .grid-table {
                width: 150px;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .grid-cell {
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
                border: 1px solid black;
                background-color: white;
                text-align: center;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 5px;
            }
            .grid-cell-text {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: steelblue;
                color: white;
                font-size: 18px;
            }
            .droppable-cell {
                background-color: lightgray;
            }
            .table-container {
                display: flex;
                position: absolute;
                left: 400px;
                top: 30px;
                margin-top: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            
            #btn_suggestion1, #btn_suggestion2 {
                background-color: lightblue;
            }
            
            #btn_resetDnD {
                background-color: pink;
            }
            "
        )
    )),
    
    actionButton("btn_suggestion1", "Suggestion 1"),
    actionButton("btn_suggestion2", "Suggestion 2"),
    actionButton("btn_resetDnD", "Reset Drag and Drop"),
    
    div(
        class = "table-container",
        div(
            class = "grid-table",
            id = "my_grid",
            div(
                class = "grid-row",
                div(class = "grid-cell grid-cell-text", "my_grid"),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_1", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_2", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_3", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_4", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_5", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_6", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_7", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", "")
            )
        ),
        
        orderInput('letters', 'Letters', items = LETTERS[1:7],
                   connect = connections) # defined above
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    shinyjs::js$pageCol(df)
    
    observeEvent(input$btn_suggestion1, {
        shinyjs::disable("btn_suggestion1")
        shinyjs::js$setSuggestion(1)
        shinyjs::enable("btn_suggestion1")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$btn_suggestion2, {
        shinyjs::disable("btn_suggestion2")
        shinyjs::js$setSuggestion(2)
        shinyjs::enable("btn_suggestion2")
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$btn_resetDnD, {
        shinyjs::disable("btn_resetDnD")
        shinyjs::js$resetDnD()
        shinyjs::enable("btn_resetDnD")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is perfectly done. Now I will try to implement to my original app. Thanks @Jan!

Comment: Ok. I tried a while and made it work for one `my_grid`. But somehow I am not able to transfer to more grids like `my_grid2` and `my_grid3` in analogy to the comments in question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76932753/drag-and-drop-with-shinyjqui-to-a-grid-table/76937125?noredirect=1#comment135632457_76937125>. And I am taking `letters` vector from 3 origin vectors like `orig_vector1`,  `origin_vector2`, `orig_vector3`. Maybe you have an idea. But if not, do not bother, these all are fine tunings. And I am perfectly satisfied with the provided answer!

Comment: Could you somehow provide a minimal example similar to above? I can't tell you what the problem is, but the approaches discussed here and in the other question should be transferable to multiple grids without limitations. What I usually would do is to run the app inside a browser and check whether there arise `JS` errors ...

Comment: Hey @Jan. thank you very much. I figured already out by myself.  For this I modified th JS by intuition and by try and error. And now all, really all work as intended!