# How can I dynamically create and save user-defined combinations in R Shiny and shinyjqui?

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny, shinyjqui

**This is my drag and drop app:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)
library(shinyjs)
library(dplyr)


###### part 1 ------------------------------------------------------------------
#creating the list of items
df <- structure(list(AG = c("A",  "B", "C", "D")),
                row.names = c(NA,-4L), class = "data.frame")

# cells of table
connections1 <- paste0("droppable_cell", ifelse(1:2 == 1, "", 1:2), "_1")
connections2 <- paste0("droppable_cell", ifelse(1:2 == 1, "", 1:2), "_2")

connections <- c(connections1, connections2)

# Define a named list for vec_suggestion1 
vec_suggestion1 <- list(  
  droppable_cell_1 =   c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
  droppable_cell_2 =  c("A", "B", "B", "A")
)

# Create the data frame
my_df <- data.frame(connections = connections,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

my_df$vec_suggestion1 <- vec_suggestion1[my_df$connections]


###### part 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------

myComplexTableUI <-   div(id = "capture", class = "table-container",
                          div(class = "grid-table",
                              id = "montag",
                              div(class = "grid-row",
                                  div(class = "grid-cell grid-cell-text", "Montag"),
                                  lapply(1:2, function(i) {
                                    div(id = paste0("droppable_cell_", i), class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", "")
                                  })
                              )
                          )
                        
                        )

###### part 3 ------------------------------------------------------------------
# my js

jsCode <- "
$(function() {
    function createSortable(day) {
        $('[id^=droppable_cell' + day + '_]').sortable({
            connectWith: '#A, #B, [id^=droppable_cell' + day + '_]',
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                $(this).append(ui.draggable);
            }
        });
    }

    createSortable('1'); // For day1
    createSortable('2'); // For day2

  $('[id^=droppable_cell]').on('sortupdate', function(e, ui) {
        var cellId = $(this).attr('id');
        var item = ui.item.text();
        Shiny.setInputValue('dropEvent', {cell: cellId, item: item}, {priority: 'event'});
    });
});

shinyjs.pageCol = function(params) {
    $('[id^=droppable_cell]').sortable({
        connectWith: '#A, #B, [id^=droppable_cell_1], [id^=droppable_cell_2]',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).append(ui.draggable);
        }
    });

    var dataArray = Object.values(params[0]);
    dataArray = dataArray[0].map((col, i) => dataArray.map(row => row[i]));

    console.log('dataArray: ', dataArray);

    var cacheA = $('#A').html();
    var cacheB = $('#B').html();

    var cacheGridCells1 = $('[id^=droppable_cell_1]').html();

shinyjs.setSuggestion = function (idxSuggestion) {
  $.each(dataArray, function (index, value) {
    var cellSelector = '#' + dataArray[index][0];
    var classIndex = idxSuggestion === 1 ? 1 : 2;
    
    // Retrieve the items for the current cell from dataArray
    var items = dataArray[index][idxSuggestion];
    if (typeof items === 'string') {
      items = [items]; // Convert to array if there is only one item
    }
    
    // Clear the cell content
    $(cellSelector).html('');
    
    // Append each item to the cell
    $.each(items, function (i, item) {
      if (item === null) {
        return true;
      }
      
      // Determine the style based on the item value
      var itemStyle = '';
      if (item === 'A') {
        itemStyle = 'background-color: #ffcc66;'; // Corresponding to Bootstrap's warning color
      } else if (item === 'B') {
        itemStyle = 'background-color: #5cb85c;'; // Corresponding to Bootstrap's success color
      }
      
      var cellHTML = '<div data-value=\"' + item
                   + '\" class=\"btn btn-default ui-sortable-handle\" style=\"' + itemStyle + ' margin: 1px;\" jqui_sortable_idx=\"letters__' 
                   + (index + 1).toString()
                   + '\">'
                   + item
                   + '</div>';
      
      $(cellSelector).append(cellHTML);
    });
  });
}
    shinyjs.resetDnD = function (params) {
    $('#A').html(cacheA).sortable('refresh');
    $('#B').html(cacheB).sortable('refresh');
    $('[id^=droppable_cell_1]').html(cacheGridCells1).sortable('refresh');
    }
};



      "
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode, functions = c("pageCol", "setSuggestion")),
  
  ###### part 4 ------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  # css table design
  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML("
        .custom-title-panel button {
          margin-left: 10px;
          margin-top: 10px; 
        }
        .grid-table {
          width: 220px;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .grid-cell {
          width: 100%;
          height: 210px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          background-color: white;
          text-align: left;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 5px;
        }
        .grid-cell-text {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          height: 50px;
          background-color: steelblue;
          color: white;
          font-size: 18px;
        }
        .table-container {
          display: flex;
          position: absolute;
          left: 260px;
          top: 20px;
          margin-top: 0px;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
      ")
    )
  ),
  
  ##################################################################################
  
  
  # btn reset
  tags$script(
    HTML(
      "$(document).ready(function() {
          $('#btn_resetDnD').click(function() {
            $('.droppable-cell').html(''); // Remove content from all elements with the class 'droppable_cell'
          });
        });"
    )
  ),

  
  # my items:      
  tags$div(
    style = "position: relative; height: 50px;", # Setting a height to contain the buttons
    tags$div(style = "position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 20px;",
             orderInput("A", "", items = df$AG[1], as_source = TRUE, connect = connections, width = "100%", item_class = "warning")
    ),
    tags$div(style = "position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 65px;",
             orderInput("B", "", items = df$AG[2], as_source = TRUE, connect = connections, width = "100%", item_class = "success")
    )
  ),
  
  # my table:
  myComplexTableUI,
  
  # my buttons:
  tags$div(style = "position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 260px; display: flex; flex-direction: row;",
           actionButton("btn_suggestion1", "Suggestion1"),
           actionButton("btn_resetDnD", "Reset")
           
  )
  )


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  shinyjs::js$pageCol(my_df)
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_suggestion1, {
    shinyjs::disable("btn_suggestion1")
    shinyjs::js$setSuggestion(1)
    shinyjs::enable("btn_suggestion1")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**The app is doing basically this:**
[image]

I would like to dynamically create the 'vec_suggestion1' input, which is currently hardcoded. I want the system to recognize and save the user’s input when they drag it to 'droppable_cell1'.

```
vec_suggestion1 <- list(  
  droppable_cell_1 =   c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
  droppable_cell_2 =  c("A", "B", "B", "A")
)
```

I am aiming to provide the user with the ability to drag and drop their ideal combinations of A and B. This information should be dynamically saved to 'vec_suggestion2'. Subsequently, any additional combinations of A's and B's should also be saved, but to 'vec_suggestion3', 'vec_suggestion4', and so on. Along with the creation of each new vector, a corresponding new button should be added, such as 'btn_suggestion2', 'btn_suggestion3', etc.

Comment: Your example is quite lengthy. Is this really needed? To me it is deterrent. Furthermore, I don't understand what you are trying to achive. `vec_suggestion1` shouly be generated dynamically - in which way? Random? combination of 4? What is the trigger to save a selection (how do we know the user is finished)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The original App is far Bagger. I tried to implement the Minimal reproducible example with all functionality. The triggern would be a Button to push. The idea is, at the start you can drag and drop A or B into the cell Montag. You decide how many A and B and which combination. This combination should then be saved in a list like vec_suggestion1. After this is done we can call the combination with a Button

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Wouldn't it be easier to create a list of the combinations saved by the user, which can be selected via `selectInput` and a single load button?

Comment: I am grateful for any Suggestion. Here is a question of mine why the App deceloped this way: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76954447/implement-drag-and-drop-functionality-using-an-observeevent-triggered-by-an-acti>.

Comment: How do you access the current state of your `orderInputs`? I see inputs: `A_over, A_drop, A_out, A_dragging, A_dropped, B_over, B_drop, B_out, B_dragging, B_dropped, dropEvent`, but it seems input$A and input$B aren't populated - I guess due to the custom JS.

Comment: @ismirsehregal. the suggestions are generate in #part1 of the code. To simplify, imagine a user dragging items A or B into an area labeled "Montag," creating a sequence like A, B, A (though real-life combinations would be more complex). to be continued....

Comment: Now, envision multiple such areas, extending from "Dienstag" to "Freitag," where the user forms sequences by dragging and dropping items A and B. Suppose the user crafts a unique combination they wish to preserve. To address this, I conceived the idea of storing these combinations in a vector, as I have already done with vec_suggestion1: 'vec_suggestion1 <- list(  
  droppable_cell_1 =   c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
  droppable_cell_2 =  c("A", "B", "B", "A")
)'. I would like to save the new combination in say vec_suggestion2. and call it with a new button: `btn_suggestion2`.

Comment: Is the "drag-and-drop" element of the GUI critical?

Comment: The drag and drop functionality is the code elemnet of the App. What do you mean with critical?

Comment: Would you accept a solution that didn't use "drag-and-drop" but gave you the same underlying functionality with a different GUI?

Comment: Please show me. Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77268995/how-to-make-updateorderinput-from-shinyjqui-to-pass-a-list-of-item-classes) a follow-up question can be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach drops the custom JS and uses an `orderInput` for each cell, which simplifies keeping track of the lists. For now I dropped the `item_class` argument to keep things simple (We could handle [lists of divs](https://github.com/Yang-Tang/shinyjqui/issues/21#issuecomment-394697106) along with `jqui_sortable()` instead to save the styling). However, the procedure to save custom combinations sould be clear:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)
library(dplyr)

df <-structure(list(AG = c("A",  "B", "C", "D")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

# cells of table
tableOrderInputIds <- paste0("Montag", "_droppable_cell_", 1:2)

# Define a named list for vec_suggestion1
# should vec_suggestions be global? Shared across shiny sessions?
if (file.exists("vec_suggestions.RData")) {
  load(file = "vec_suggestions.RData")
} else {
  vec_suggestions <- list(
    vec_suggestion1 = list(
      Montag_droppable_cell_1 = c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
      Montag_droppable_cell_2 = c("A", "B", "B", "A")
    ),
    vec_suggestion2 = list(
      Montag_droppable_cell_1 = c("B", "B", "B", "B"),
      Montag_droppable_cell_2 = c("A", "A", "A", "A")
    )
  )
}

###### part 2 ------------------------------------------------------------------

myComplexTableUI <- div(id = "capture",
                        class = "table-container",
                        div(
                          class = "grid-table",
                          id = "montag",
                          div(
                            class = "grid-row",
                            div(class = "grid-cell grid-cell-text", "Montag"),
                            lapply(tableOrderInputIds, function(x) {
                              div(
                                orderInput(
                                  inputId = x,
                                  label = NULL,
                                  items = NULL,
                                  connect = tableOrderInputIds,
                                  width = "100%",
                                  style = "min-height: 200px;"
                                ),
                                class = "grid-cell"
                              )
                            })
                          )
                        ))

ui <- fluidPage(
  # css table design
  tags$head(tags$style(
    HTML(
      "
        .custom-title-panel button {
          margin-left: 10px;
          margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .grid-table {
          width: 220px;
          border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .grid-cell {
          width: 100%;
          height: 210px;
          border: 1px solid black;
          background-color: white;
          text-align: left;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 5px;
        }
        .grid-cell-text {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
          height: 50px;
          background-color: steelblue;
          color: white;
          font-size: 18px;
        }
        .table-container {
          display: flex;
          position: absolute;
          left: 260px;
          top: 20px;
          margin-top: 0px;
          overflow: hidden;
        }
      "
    )
  )),
  # my items:
  tags$div(
    style = "position: relative; height: 50px;",
    # Setting a height to contain the buttons
    tags$div(
      style = "position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 20px;",
      orderInput(
        "A",
        "",
        items = df$AG[1],
        as_source = TRUE,
        connect = tableOrderInputIds,
        width = "100%"
      )
    ),
    tags$div(
      style = "position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 65px;",
      orderInput(
        "B",
        "",
        items = df$AG[2],
        as_source = TRUE,
        connect = tableOrderInputIds,
        width = "100%"
      )
    )
  ),
  # my table:
  myComplexTableUI,
  # my buttons:
  column(
    12,
    selectizeInput(
      "select_suggestion",
      "Select / Add suggestion",
      choices = names(vec_suggestions),
      multiple = FALSE,
      options = list('create' = TRUE,
                     'persist' = FALSE)
    ),
    actionButton("load_suggestion", "Load suggestion"),
    actionButton("btn_resetDnD", "Reset"),
    actionButton("save_suggestion", "Save suggestion"),
    style = "position: absolute; top: 500px; left: 20px;"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # user_suggestion <- reactiveValues(droppable_cell_1 = NULL, droppable_cell_2 = NULL)
  user_suggestion <- do.call(shiny::reactiveValues, setNames(vector(mode = "list", length = length(tableOrderInputIds)), tableOrderInputIds))
  
  observeEvent(input$load_suggestion, {
    lapply(tableOrderInputIds, function(x) {
      updateOrderInput(session, inputId = x, items = vec_suggestions[[input$select_suggestion]][[x]])
    })
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$save_suggestion, {
    # should vec_suggestions be global? Shared across shiny sessions?
    vec_suggestions <<- modifyList(vec_suggestions, setNames(list(reactiveValuesToList(user_suggestion)), input$select_suggestion))
    save(vec_suggestions, file = "vec_suggestions.RData")
    showNotification("Saved suggestions to disk.")
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$btn_resetDnD, {
    lapply(tableOrderInputIds, function(x) {
      updateOrderInput(session, inputId = x, items = list())
    })
  })
  
  observe({
    lapply(tableOrderInputIds, function(x) {
      user_suggestion[[x]] <- input[[x]]
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: This looks perfect. I will try to implement to my original work!!!

Comment: Could you have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77268995/how-to-make-updateorderinput-from-shinyjqui-to-pass-a-list-of-item-classes) please? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few steps you can follow to achieve this in R Shiny

Create a reactiveValues object to store the combination vectors, then to update when the user drags and drops. could be initiated as empty list.

now to update the reactiveValues object in the "sortupdate" event: In the "sortupdate" event, retrieve the cell id and the item dragged, and then use the `update` function to update the `values$suggestions` object with the new combination. now adding a button and corresponding action using `renderUI` and `uiOutput` functions. Within `renderUI` now using `observeEvent` function for defining actions for all buttons

In event, using the `renderUI` function to generate a new list of items for `droppable_cell1` and `droppable_cell2` based on values in `values$suggestions` for particular combination index.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Could you provide a code example?