# How to make an orderInput item resizeable with jqui_resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, r, shinyjs, shinyjqui

**Update:** Here is graphical explanation from what I want:
There are to features: 1. resizing with the mouse and 2. rotating the text.

[image]
This is a follow-up question to this [Drag and drop with shinyjqui to a grid-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76932753/drag-and-drop-with-shinyjqui-to-a-grid-table/76937125?noredirect=1#comment135632457_76937125).

First answer:
I am trying to make the **item or button with the label A** resizeable like explained here https://yang-tang.github.io/shinyjqui/: 'Resizable: Change the size of an element using the mouse.'

Is this possible? I have tried the generic function of the package  `jqui_sortable` and also a custom JS code like in the example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

connections <- paste0("droppable_cell_", 1) # id of the grid cells

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(
      JS(
        "
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function() {
$('#letters').resizable({
alsoResize: '.shinyjqui-sortable-item',
minHeight: 20,
minWidth: 20
});
});


$(function() {
$('[id^=droppable_cell]').sortable({
connectWith: '#letters',
drop: function(event, ui) {
$(this).append(ui.draggable);
}
})
});
"
      )
    ),
# some styling
tags$style(
  HTML(
    "
.grid-table {
width: 150px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
.grid-cell {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px;
}
.grid-cell-text {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
height: 100%;
background-color: steelblue;
color: white;
font-size: 18px;
}
.droppable-cell {
background-color: lightgray;
}
.table-container {
display: flex;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
top: 10px;
margin-top: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}
"
  )
)
  ),

div(
  class = "table-container",
  div(
    class = "grid-table",
    id = "my_grid",
    div(
      class = "grid-row",
      div(class = "grid-cell grid-cell-text", "my_grid"),
      div(id = "droppable_cell_1", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
    )
  ),
  
  orderInput('letters', 'Letters', items = LETTERS[1],
             connect = connections) # defined above
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: It is possible, try replacing the `#letters` selector in your `JS` with `.btn`. This works for me, but may need to be extended in order to improve the visual appearance of the resized item.

Comment: Incredible. Now I got it. Have you any idea to rotate the text? And please provide both as answer!

Comment: Is it acceptable to have a solution where the whole button is rotated? The resizing handler would then appear in the top right corner of the button.

Comment: Okay, hopefully last question: What event shall trigger the rotation of the button? Currently I have it `on resize`, but this is maybe not want you want, consider e.g. the case that the user only stretches the button horizontally ...

Comment: It is not necessary that there is a trigger, but if we need one then within resize is ok. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach for implementing the two features.

For the resizeable buttons, your `JS` is already good, but you should rather apply it to `.btn`, not to `#letters`.

The rotated buttons could be obtained by

```
$('.btn').on('resize', function() {
    $(this).css({'transform': 'rotate(270deg)',
                 'line-height': $(this).height().toString() + 'px'});
})
```

This will have the following effects:

1. If a button is resized (you can of course delete or alter this trigger), then the button gets rotated by 270 degrees. Notice that what is more desirable is to only rotate the text of the button, not the button itself, but I think one has to manipulate the `HTML` more in-depth for obtaining this. Also notice that `writing-mode: sideways-rl` is suitable for this, but unfortunately this is currently not supported by all browsers.
2. Since the buttons have `text-align: center` and `vertical-align: middle` by default, the `line-height: $(this).height().toString() + 'px'` is sufficient for setting that the text of the button (here: "A") always will be displayed in the center of the button after resizing.

This is how it could look like after resizing:

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

connections <- paste0("droppable_cell_", 1) # id of the grid cells

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        tags$script(
            JS(
                "
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function() {
    $('.btn').resizable({
        alsoResize: '.shinyjqui-sortable-item',
        minHeight: 20,
        minWidth: 20
});

$('.btn').on('resize', function() {
    $(this).css({'transform': 'rotate(270deg)',
                 'line-height': $(this).height().toString() + 'px'});
})
});


$(function() {
$('[id^=droppable_cell]').sortable({
connectWith: '#letters',
drop: function(event, ui) {
$(this).append(ui.draggable);
}
})
});
"
            )
        ),
        # some styling
        tags$style(
            HTML(
                "
.grid-table {
width: 150px;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
.grid-cell {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: white;
text-align: center;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px;
}
.grid-cell-text {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
height: 100%;
background-color: steelblue;
color: white;
font-size: 18px;
}
.droppable-cell {
background-color: lightgray;
}
.table-container {
display: flex;
position: absolute;
left: 10px;
top: 10px;
margin-top: 0px;
overflow: hidden;
}
"
            )
        )
    ),
    
    div(
        class = "table-container",
        div(
            class = "grid-table",
            id = "my_grid",
            div(
                class = "grid-row",
                div(class = "grid-cell grid-cell-text", "my_grid"),
                div(id = "droppable_cell_1", class = "grid-cell droppable-cell", ""),
            )
        ),
        
        orderInput('letters', 'Letters', items = LETTERS[1],
                   connect = connections) # defined above
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thx @Jan. Is it possible to make the direction of resizing from bottom to top or top to bottom instead of primarily from left to right. Or in other words finally the button should get a height of 400px and width of 50px, all done with resizing.

Comment: Yes, but I have to think about how to implement it. However, if you already now the target width and height of the button, do you really need manual resizing per mouse here? This could be implemented by `CSS` directly.

Comment: Thanks, @Jan. In my app, I have 10 items, each with its own orderInput. So far, they all have the same height and width, which I've implemented with CSS. However, I'd like to change the height after performing a drag-and-drop action. I'm not concerned about the rotating aspect; my main challenge is implementing your resizable code into my app. I suspect there's some JS code in my app that's causing interference, but I'm confident I'll figure it out. Don't worry, and thank you very much for your patience and support. I've learned a lot this week!

Comment: @TarJae I think you need the [handles option](https://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles).